# Low-level multimedia and mouse support in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

I'm in the planning phase for a new application I'm writing for OS X. This would be my first application using Cocoa.  The app requires API functionality to perform the following tasks:

- Capture arbitrary portions of the screen (up to several frames per second) (also displaying the mouse pointer, if possible)
- Capture all audio output being generated by the sound card
- Manipulate the mouse programmatically (move and click)

Does Cocoa have API functionality for these requirements? If not, what would be a good alternative?

(Note: From my requirements, it may seem that the application could be malware. However, I assure you it is not - it will be a sort of macro recorder/playback mechanism for streamlining media consumption). Thanks, everyone! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Here's some sample code for screen recording using OpenGL: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004445 It doesn't capture the mouse, but you can artificially superimpose it using NSImage.
- For audio recording, there's an opensource application called [Soundflower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) that reroutes the computer's audio output and makes the OS treat it like input device. Warning, it is very very complicated as is most programatic audio manipulation in OS X.
- Mouse manipulation can be done with CGPostMouseEvent:

  ```
  CGPostMouseEvent(CGPoint mouseCursorPosition, boolean_t updateMouseCursorPosition, CGButtonCount buttonCount, boolean_t mouseButtonDown)
  ```